# Reading subset of GeoTIFF file without having to read whole file first?

Tags: python, gdal, remote-sensing, geotiff-tiff

I have a set of GeoTIFF files which I have generated from the MODIS LST Product and have used the coordinate information present within the file to work out the index of my 'pixel of interest'/study site. My aim is to extract the data value at this index and so far have been using this code within python:

```
myfile = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)
value = myfile[y_index, x_index]
```

which works just fine. This generates the result I want but I am having to read in the whole data file first, before obtaining the result I require. Is it possible to read just my 'pixel of interest' or a subset of the data without having to read the whole file into memory beforehand?

I am using Python and the gdal module within it.

Comment: For sure it is possible. Probably you want to use ReadBlock http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#ad80cecc562fd48f5783677de625360ac If you want fast access to a subset you must use tiffs which are written as tiled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added a solution to this question below using the method I had already stated, I was trying to make things more complicated than need be! Overthinking strikes again!

Comment: You may want to study and compare how the special GDAL tool "gdallocationinfo" does the job https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/apps/gdallocationinfo.cpp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was trying to make things more complicated than they needed to be, **one simple solution is as follows**:

When using ReadAsArray(), the function works as follows:

```
data = myfile.ReadAsArray(x_offset, y_offset, x_size, y_size)
```

So if you use:

```
data = myfile.ReadAsArray(x_index, y_index, 1, 1)
```

This will read in JUST one pixel.

But the code can be adapted to read in a 3x3 window etc. using:

```
data = myfile.ReadAsArray(x_index - 1, y_index - 1, 3, 3)
```